# jQuery ajax return success data

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I need to use a dynamic URL in colorbox, but the `link` variable is empty. I was tried it without using a function, simply `link = data;`, but it is not working.

```
var link = '';

function getURL(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/designesia/bookAjax.php",
        cache: false,
        type: "POST", 
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            link = data;
        }
    });
}

$(".iframe").click(getURL);

$(".iframe").colorbox({
    iframe:true, 
    width: "50%", 
    height: "80%", 
    href: link, 
});
```

Comment: Try `console.log(data);` to check what are you getting in response. If response in blank, post your `PHP code` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is working:

```
        $(".iframe").click(function() {
            var link = '';
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/designesia/bookAjax.php",
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                type: "POST", 
                data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
                success: function(data){ 
                    link = data; 
                }
            });
            $(".iframe").colorbox({
                iframe:true, 
                innerWidth: "45%",
                height: "90%", 
                href: link,             
            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the colorbox code in the function that receives the success:

```
function getURL(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/designesia/bookAjax.php",
        cache: false,
        type: "POST", 
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success:function(data){
           $(".iframe").colorbox({
               iframe:true, 
               width: "50%", 
               height: "80%", 
               href: data, 
           }); 
        }
    });
}
```

The problem was you were setting the value of link before receiving a response or even responding to the click event.  Doing it this way ensures that once a request goes out you apply the data as the href.

### Update

The element .iframe should be an anchor link

```
<a href="" class="iframe">My Link</a>
```

And the code should trigger a click if it is supposed to open a window automatically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.example').click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/designesia/bookAjax.php",
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                $(".iframe").colorbox({
                   iframe:true, 
                   width: "50%", 
                   height: "80%", 
                   href: data 
               }).click();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought this, and used it, but not working ... When I clicked the button, no showing iframe.

Comment: What type of data are you returning? Try doing a console.log(data); To make sure the data is what you are expecting.

Comment: It's a string (link).

Comment: Oh is the javascript you're running in the head of the html?

Comment: Of course ... :) If i will put manually link to colorbox 'href', working well!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but now working.

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('.example').click(function(event){
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/designesia/bookAjax.php",
                cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                    $(".iframe").colorbox({
                       iframe:true, 
                       width: "50%", 
                       height: "80%", 
                       href: data 
                   }).click();
                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
        <div id="b_editDates">
         <h3>Book in Booking.Com</h3>
             <form method="post" id="myForm" action="">
             <div class="b_availFormInner">

                 <div class="b_availDatesInner">

                     <span class="text-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Check In Date</span>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="datep1" id="datep1" style="cursor:default" value="<? echo date('d-m-Y'); ?>" class="form-control" readonly />

                 </div>
                <br>

                 <div class="b_availDatesInner">
                     <span class="text-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Check Out Date</span>
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" name="datep2" id="datep2" style="cursor:default" value="<? echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($stop_date . ' + 1 day')); ?>" class="form-control" readonly />

                 </div>
                 <br>
                 <div id="b_availSubmit">
                    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Check NOW!" id="bookingcheck" name="bookingcheck" class="btn btn-custom btn-large"/> -->

                 </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
         <div id="div1"></div>

        <a class="btn btn-custom btn-large iframe" >Check NOW!</a>
```

PHP code:

```
$datep1 = explode("-", $_POST['datep1']);
$datep2 = explode("-", $_POST['datep2']);

$link = array(
    "aid" => 'XX',
    "hotel_id" => 'XX',
    "lang" => "en",
    "pb" => "",
    "stage" => 0,
    "hostname" => "www.booking.com",
    "checkin_monthday" => $datep1[0],
    "checkin_year_month" => $datep1[2].'-'.$datep1[1],
    "checkout_monthday" => $datep2[0],
    "checkout_year_month" => $datep2[2].'-'.$datep2[1]
);

echo "XX?".http_build_query($link);
```